# String frequency search not finding all words

Tags: java, string, text, frequency, word-frequency

I am trying to implement a string frequency search algorithm that parses a `jokes.txt` file and gets the number of occurences of each unique word in the test. 
The algorithm should consider case sensitivity and make "a" and "A" both unique. As of now, the algorithm seems to skip the first occurence of "a" in the test and many other words later on.

Furthermore, the `words` array contains every word in the text. Somehow, the loop within the `(!isDuplicate)` condition skips over the "a" and doesn't increase the `count`.

**jokes.txt**

```
I wondered why the baseball was getting bigger.
Then it hit me.

Police were called to a day care
where a 3-yr-old was resisting a rest.
...
```

**WordCounter.java**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class WordCounter {
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    //prints number of words in the  file
    public void numOfWords(Scanner key1) {
        int counter = 1;
        while(key1.hasNext()) {
            words.add(key1.next().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", ""));

        }
    }

    //Takes word as parameter and returns frequency of that word
    public void frequencyCounter(Scanner key1) {
        ArrayList <String> freqWords = new ArrayList<String>();
        int count = 1;
        int counter = 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++){
            boolean isDuplicate = false;
            for (String s: freqWords){
                if (s.contains(words.get(i).trim()))
                    isDuplicate =true;
            }

            if (!isDuplicate){

                for(int j = i + 1; j < words.size(); j++){
                    if(words.get(i).equals(words.get(j))){
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                freqWords.add(count + "-" + words.get(i));
                Collections.sort(freqWords, Collections.reverseOrder());
                count = 1;     
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < freqWords.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print((i+1) + "       ");
            System.out.println(freqWords.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: @shmosel just did it

Comment: Still unclear what the problem is. Tell us what's actually happening instead of what you imagine the code is doing.

Comment: @shmosel I ran the debuger coutless time to track what is happening and the 'a' is skipped. I have no clue what is the cause of that.

Comment: Skipped where? When? From what?

Comment: @shmosel Some words (like 'a') in the `words` array are not copied into the `freqWords` array when I call `freqWords.add(count + "-" + words.get(i));`

Answer (score 2):

Your logic for determining duplicates is a bit incorrect:

```
        boolean isDuplicate = false;
        for (String s: freqWords){
            if (s.contains(words.get(i).trim()))
                isDuplicate =true;
        }
```

This will make isDuplicate to true if words.get(i) is "a" and s is "apple" because apple contains "a". Check if the word in s matches the words.get(i) exactly.

Answer (score 0):

just edit my wrong answer:

But might be that the contains() makes the problem, as the API tells us it searches for a Charsequenz in the String. This means you are basically searching for the Charsequenz „a“ in every word and tell it is a duplicate. So it counts „day“ up one because you are searching for „a“

In my opinion it would be better to use a HashMap for searching duplicates and would be even faster. And you can count how many there are in the values.

Comment: `^` is negation.

Comment: Editted to what i think is the solution you arensearching for